# Do I need AdSense for an ads.txt?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, cpanel, affiliate, monetize

I have signed up to be a game publisher with various platforms, and they all require that I add information to an ads.txt file. When I looked it up, all the articles mention Google AdSense. I don’t want any ads on my site other than those from the third-party game affiliates.

Can I add an ads.txt file to my root directory without AdSense?

Comment: If you don't add the adsense code to your site, ads won't display.  It sounds like they are going to insert their own ads...and take the money from clicks.

Comment: Yes, they are going to take money from clicks. I embed their games on my own website. It’s an affiliate program, so we share revenue.

Comment: So you need to clarify the question, if the agreement is as you say, then why the problem with ads.txt?

Comment: @Steve I really just don’t understand how ads.txt works. Can I create an ads.txt file in my root directory, paste the code that they give me inside, and start using the service? Or do I need something provided by Google AdSense to create a functional ads.txt?

Comment: We cannot really answer this because it depends on what ad network these platforms are using (most likely it is AdSense). You can read about `ads.txt` and what it's for [here](https://iabtechlab.com/ads-txt/). Google provides a guide on how to [create an ads.txt file for your site](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7532444?hl=en).

Comment: @dan thanks I will check it out.